# How to update through cockpit api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest

I need to be able to update through the cockpit api but it creates a new entry.

I have tried to use the same credentials but still made a new entry.

```
Create / Update collection entries

fetch('/api/collections/save/posts?token=xxtokenxx', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data: {...}
    })
})
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(entry => console.log(entry));
```

the code for creating and updating is the same, I need an example in which it shows me how I can use this api to update my code.
the API can be found https://getcockpit.com/documentation/api/collections

Comment: I don't know the API definition you are trying to use, but the RFC 2616  states that you have to use PUT when you want to modify a singular resource which is already a part of resources collection. PUT replaces the resource in its entirety. Use PATCH if request updates part of the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future ref, you need to include " _id " in your query to update the entry.

Comment: how to include that ?

Comment: @Zorox in data: {...} you need to add _id of what you wish to update